# How To Play Sound When I Click In The Button Which I Created Using Tkinter Using Python

Tags: python, tkinter, button, audio, click

I want to play sound when i click the button which i have created by python tkinter to determine that the button has been clicked or not. if button has been clicked it will play sound and if button has been not clicked it will not play the sound.

Comment: look at here <https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-play-sounds-in-python-with-tkinter/>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.